# Getting bug in recursive functions?

Tags: javascript

I am using an array with nested object of array. Assigning the values in array's values according to input line index, values are passed into the array's indexed value. I have checked the condition that if in array object is there, it converts it into array and call the recursive function and it calls recursion until the object's array's value is full but don't know why it is not working properly. Please help me in this bug

```
(function($) {
  var xmlOutput = document.querySelector(".xmlOutput");
  let templateStore = [];
  let preservedEntriesValue = [];
  let selectedTemplate = [];

  function generateDOMDropdown(selectedID) {
    let optionTemplate = templateStore.map(function(entry) {
      return `<option value="${
        entry.id
      }" ${entry.id === selectedID ? "selected" : ""}>${entry.name}</option>`;
    });
    $("#select").html(optionTemplate);
  }

  function processEntries(entries) {
    let output = "";
    for (const entry of entries) {
      output += entry;
    }
    return output;
  }

  function parseJSONToXML(input) {
    const domStructure = input.entriesValue.map(function(tagObj) {
      if (typeof tagObj === "string") {
        return `<${tagObj}></${tagObj}>`;
      } else if (Array.isArray(tagObj)) {
        if (tagObj.length > 1) {
          return `<${tagObj[0]}>${tagObj[1]}</${tagObj[0]}>`;
        } else if (tagObj.length == 1) {
          return `<${tagObj[0]}></${tagObj[0]}>`;
        }
      } else {
        const outerTag = Object.keys(tagObj).pop();
        const innerDOM = parseJSONToXML({ entriesValue: tagObj[outerTag] });
        return `<${outerTag}>${processEntries(innerDOM)}</${outerTag}>`;
      }
    });
    return domStructure;
  }

  function preFillSelected() {
    const root = selectedTemplate.root;
    const domStructure = parseJSONToXML(selectedTemplate);
    xmlOutput.innerText = vkbeautify.xml(
      `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><${root}>${processEntries(
        domStructure
      )}</${root}>`,
      5
    );
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: window.location.origin + "/templates.json",
    success: function(data) {
      templateStore = data;
      if (data.length > 0) {
        selectedTemplate = data[0];
        generateDOMDropdown(selectedTemplate.id);
        preservedEntriesValue = selectedTemplate.entriesValue;
        preFillSelected();
        $("#select")
          .off("change")
          .on("change", function() {
            selectedTemplate = templateStore[$("#select").val()];
            preservedEntriesValue = selectedTemplate.entriesValue;
            preFillSelected();
            window.template = selectedTemplate;
          });
      }
    }
  });

  function generateValueJSON(
    template,
    lines,
    inputLen,
    templateLen,
    flatLen,
    cidx
  ) {
    cidx = cidx || 0;
    // console.log('Entry', lines, template, cidx);
    return Array.from(template.entriesValue.entries()).map(([idx, entry]) => {
      console.log("Lines", lines);
      if (idx < lines.length) {
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
          return [entry[0], lines[idx]];
        } else if (typeof entry === "object") {
          // debugger;

          const outerTag = Object.keys(entry).pop();
          const innerLength = entry[outerTag].length;
          if (cidx === 0) cidx = idx;
          const outerIdx = cidx + innerLength;
          // console.log((flatLen - templateLen - inputLen));
          // console.log({ flatLen, templateLen, inputLen, outerIdx, cidx, idx });
          const innerObj = generateValueJSON(
            { entriesValue: entry[outerTag] },
            lines.slice(idx, outerIdx),
            inputLen,
            templateLen,
            flatLen,
            idx
          );
          //   cidx = 0;
          entry[outerTag] = innerObj;
          return entry;
        }
        return [entry, lines[idx]];
      }
      return entry;
    });
  }

  function mapLength(template) {
    return template.entriesValue
      .map((entry) => {
        return typeof entry === "object"
          ? [Object.keys(entry), Object.values(entry)]
          : entry;
      })
      .flat(3).length;
  }

  $("#txtInput").on("keyup", function() {
    const lines = $(this)
      .val()
      .split("\n\n")
      .map((v) => v.trim().replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
    // console.log(preservedEntriesValue);
    selectedTemplate.entriesValue = preservedEntriesValue;
    templateLength = mapLength(selectedTemplate);
    const newEntriesValue = generateValueJSON(
      selectedTemplate,
      lines,
      lines.length,
      selectedTemplate.entriesValue.length,
      templateLength
    );
    // console.log(newEntriesValue);
    selectedTemplate.entriesValue = newEntriesValue;
    preFillSelected();
  });
})(window.jQuery, Node);





//here is the data array
[{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Template Name 2",
        "root": "media",
        "entriesValue": [
            "mediaid",
            "category",
            "provider",
            "date",
            "caption_photo_1",
            {
                "image": [
                    "imageid",
                    "type",
                    "width",
                    "hfive"
                ]
            },
            {
                "video": [
                    "name",
                    "type",
                    "bitrate",
                    "size",
                    "width",
                    "hfive",
                    "headline",
                    "summary"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Template Name 1",
        "root": "article",
        "entriesValue": [
            "author",
            "headline",
            "cats",
            "subcats",
            "image",
            "video",
            "tags",
            "summary",
            "content"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Template Name 3",
        "root": "article",
        "entriesValue": [
            "author",
            "headline",
            "cats",
            "subcats",
            "image",
            "video",
            "summary",
            "content",
            "keyword"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Template Name 4",
        "root": "root",
        "entriesValue": [
            "description",
            "title",
            "languageId",
            "categoryIds"
        ]
    }
]
```

At first input it work properly but in second input it passes the value in in both object

```
<image>
      <imageid>Correct</imageid>
      <type>bug</type>
      <width>bug</width>
      <hfive></hfive>``
 </image>
 <video>
      <name>bug</name>
      <type>bug</type>
      <bitrate></bitrate>
      <size></size>
      <width></width>
      <hfive></hfive>
      <headline></headline>
      <summary></summary>
 </video>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and pinpoint the issue further. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57107134/edit) and then `[<>]` and show only what is relevant. If the AJAX works, then leave it out

Comment: ajax is work properly.